# Ruby on rails: issue while saving changes in record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an scaffolded controller where in Update action I have:

```
def update
    if @offer.update(offer_params)
        redirect_to @offer
    else
        render "edit"
    end 
end
def edit

end
```

And this code gives me an error:

```
undefined method `main_id_changed?' for #<Offer:0x00000004206c10>
```

Other actions like Destroy, Create, Show - works great.

Has anybody faced with such kind of problem?

Thank you in advance!

EDITED:

In controller:

```
before_action :find_offer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

private

def offer_params
    params.require(:offer).permit(:title, :company, :description, :telephone, :adress, :economy, :url, :category_id, :image, :lat, :lng, :image_file_name, :city_id)
end

def find_offer
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
end
```

In model:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :main, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :city

has_attached_file :image, 
    styles: { thumb: "64x64", small: "100x100>", medium: "300x210#", large: "600x600" },
    url: '/img/:class/:id/:style.:extension',
    path: ':rails_root/public:url'

validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Comment: What's inside your `offer_params`? What are the parameters that sent to this controller action? Is `main_id_changed` an attribute of your `@offer`'s model?

Comment: Add your `Offer` model code to the questiion

Comment: @RSB @nayiaw , Hello guys, I've updated post. I dont have  `main_id_changed` method at all. I think it was added by some gem, like pagination or paperclip, but not sure.

Comment: @inffy check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permit `id` field in your `offer_params` method

```
params.require(:offer).permit(:id, :title, :company, :description, :telephone, :adress, :economy, :url, :category_id, :image, :lat, :lng, :image_file_name, :city_id)
```

and, remove `counter_cache: true`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, permit id field didn't make a sense. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Why have you added `counter_cache: true` ?

Comment: Wow, removing `counter_cache` fixes the problem! Actually I added this, because of some tutorial I used to create relations between controllers. I'm a bit new, so put it there with no understanding how `countner_cache` works. Have you an idea why this parameter behavior like this ?

Comment: For more details about the `counter_cache` option, follow this link http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to